# Is something wrong with my frequency selections for a buck converter controller?

Tags: frequency, dc-dc-converter, buck, converter

I'm designing a processor-controlled buck converter. I'm seeing some instabilities, which I suspect may be due to improper frequency selection at different points in my system. I'm trying to regulate output current, with a result that looks like a sawtooth. Current drops to a trough, I get some short pulses which seem to stop the drop, then I get one much longer pulse which kicks the current up to a peak. No pulses until the next through. Average current as measured both by my control system and by an external clamp are regulating to, say, within 20% of my setpoint. Not good enough for my spec.

- Switching frequency: 12 kHz
- A/D sampling frequency: 12 kHz
- Control loop update frequency: 12 kHz (observed)
- Anti-aliasing RC filter on feedback signals entering A/D converter: single pole, 1 kHz corner frequency
- Digital filtering: None
- Choke: ~2 mH

Should I perhaps be sampling faster? Updating my control loop slower? Using an anti-alias filter with a higher corner frequency? Is there some obvious flaw in this control scheme as I've described it? In general, how would one properly select these frequencies and values relative to each other?

Comment: What instabilities are you seeing? This is important - it's like going to the doctor and having him guess what is wrong with you.

Comment: I was thinking of it more like a blind man going to the doctor and asking if there's a giant wound where he may or may not have shot himself in the foot... but I'll add more detail. :)

Comment: What to what bandwidth are you trying to regulat the output?

Comment: @OlinLathrop I'm not sure I even understand what you're asking. Can you perhaps dumb the question down a level?

Comment: I've read enough to absolutely know I'd need a circuit diagram. The fact that you're current regulating was the tipping-point. I'm sure in asking for a picture of what the waveform looks like too including peaks and times. The big omission is load and whether you have it stable at any load and what loads you are trying. I am also a little concerned that you may not have some hardware that controls the "on" drive to the IGBT and switches it off when you reach some near-insane peak current value (to prevent really large cyclical "lumps" of energy being forwarded to the output capacitor).

Comment: I'll also add this - can you get it (as a prototype) to work with a regular analogue control system?

Comment: Please keep in mind, my goal with this question is not "help me stabilize my entire control system". It's "Is there anything obviously wrong with this combination of values"? For example, Olin's comment about the anti-aliasing filter was right on the money, and I'd love to know if anything else is odd. Don't get me wrong, I appreciate the help. But right now I'm so far over my head I don't even have time to try to gain a theoretical understanding of it all or run tests that aren't strictly necessary to getting this thing out the door. That's why I asked a very limited and specific question.

Comment: But yes, I do have a Concept IGBT driver, which includes robust desat protection, and I haven't been hitting its limits at all. And I hope to have a theoretical grasp of this entire system some day! Just... not at the expense of getting this done.

Comment: Depending on how the current is sensed, usually a current regulator only has one pole to worry about. Have you a control to Io xfer function?.. without that it will be hard to know whats going on.  Fs of 12KHz, loop BW should probably be kept less than ~500Hz. There will be some phase loss with 1kHz ADC filter, but shouldn't destabilize by itself.   Have you tried operating open loop with set Duty cycle?  It should be flawless open loop before closing loop.

Comment: Can you be clearer about this "regulating within 20% of my setpoint"? On average, is it correct but the numbers fluctuate? My questions above are wholly intended to get more information from you so that the "values" can be analysed. There is no-way that what you have provided so far is enough to analyse and anything else is guesswork and this means the answers will be speculative and likely to to attract down-votes for the answers and your originating question. Not knowing and not getting decent information about this problem doesn't help solve it.

Comment: I'm clearly having some difficulty here, which is entirely my fault. I'm trying to ask a general question. How, IN GENERAL, do you select sampling frequency vs. switching frequency vs. control loop update frequency vs. anti-aliasing filter corner frequency? We keep getting pulled into details of my specific application, which is not what I'm asking about. This is probably due to my bad choice of titles. I gave values primarily as an example. I appreciate the help, I really do, but at this point I think I need to end this question and try again.

Comment: Most converters I've designed with run at 200kHz or more. I think there might be issues with running at such low frequency.

Answer (score 3):

A buck converter in voltage mode needs what's known as a '[type-3 compensator](http://www.exar.com/common/content/document.ashx?id=1238)' to correctly compensate for the resonant peaking created by the output LC filter. The type-3 compensator has three poles and two zeroes, giving you a slope of -1, then a slope of +1, then back to -1. It will allow you sufficient gain and phase margin for stability, and allows you to cross over the gain at a -1 slope.

The system you're describing has a simple RC filter with no digital compensation, which will not give you an appropriate response. One way to solve the problem is to calculate what poles and zeroes you need for proper compensation, derive the s-domain transfer function for that compensation, then do a z-transform and implement it digitally.

A good book on the subject is [Applied Control Theory for Embedded Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750678399) by Tim Wescott, but you may want to consider bringing someone in temporarily who's skilled in the art (i.e. someone with power and control training) to get past your time constraint.

Comment: That sounds brilliant. Sadly, my background is just enough to recognize the words, and appreciate that they're in the right order. Connecting that all to reality has been something I've fought with for six years, and I've yet to find an explanation that can click with me. Can you recommend a good book or other resource that will tie all that together?

Comment: Thanks for the book recommendation! I think I can get past this particular time crunch, but this will definitely help next time around.

Answer (score 0):

There are whole books written on control system and power supply stability, "compenstation", and other schemes.  You are basically saying *"design my control system"*, or much worse, *"fix my existing ill-conceived control scheme"*.  There is no way that can be reasonably done here, especially with such sparse data.

However, a few observations:

From your description (a scope trace would be much better than the hand waving), it sounds like your supply is meta-stable but with local instability.  That is not necessarily a problem, but will reduce the apparent bandwidth of the system and increase noise.

A common cause of meta stable but locally unstable is resistance in series with the output cap.  Is it electrolytic perhaps?

12 kHz is *very* slow.  Plenty of processors can easily do 100 kHz and beyond, especially with a simple control scheme.

High pulse frequency can compensate for simple control schemes.  For example, if it's sortof working at 12 kHz, then maybe just a dumb pulse on demand system would work fine at 120 kHz.

1 kHz anti-aliasing filter!!?  I can't really say more since you haven't explained where exactly this filter is and what signal it is filtering, but that sounds like a guarantee of instability.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify that the anti-aliasing filter is on the feedbacks into the processor. Also, since you added your point 5, apparently you CAN diagnose an obvious (to you) problem in the system from the information I provided, which was in fact the question I asked. So perhaps dial the snark down a bit?

Comment: Also, as a point of interest, it's a 7kW converter, and I'm running IGBTs. 100 kHz would be a spectacularly bad idea. There might be FETs out there that could do that, but they'd cost more, the drivers would be more twitchy, and I'm on a tight timeline.

Comment: @Stephen: You might have mentioned this was doing 7 kW and that your input voltage is high enough to require IGBTs.  This is exactly why we want to see real information in the quetion.

Comment: Why would I mention information not relevant to the question I'm asking? You're trying to read this as a giant "fix my control scheme" question, when I'm instead asking specific questions about a very tiny corner of the system, a question that applies to every processor-controlled switching power supply.